# Running sysinternals strings.exe command in Jenkins batch command hangs

Tags: windows, jenkins, sysinternals

I have a windows batch command in Jenkins as a build step, and I'm doing this:

CMD /C strings.exe a.bin

And it just sits there and spins forever.  I cannot get it to work.  I have put it in a batch file, I have tried running it with start, nothing seems to work.  How do I get this to work?